# Can someone explain this piece of code to me

Tags: javascript

What does the strings in this code mean, Its part of a traffic light script and I dont know what each of the lines do.

```
var index = 0;
var variableLen = variable.length;

function nextvariableClick() {
    index++;

    if (index == variableLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = variable[index];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `variable` is an array that stores references (URIs, or paths) to images, that is fed to the `src` attribute of an image element, `<img>`. The script simple does the following logic:

- When the function is fired, it increments `index` by 1
- If index is equal to the number of images, you return it to 0 (basically "cycling" through the array
- You set the image source to the nth element of the `variable` array, by the index `index`

An intelligent guess would be that this is a image cycling function. When `nextvariableClick` is called it cycles through a list of images in the order they appear in the `variable` array.

Since the script is so simple, the best way to see what it does is to construct a functional code snippet:

```js
// Define dummy image references
var variable = [
  'https://placehold.it/500x300/e41a1c/ffffff',
  'https://placehold.it/500x300/377eb8/ffffff',
  'https://placehold.it/500x300/4daf4a/ffffff',
  'https://placehold.it/500x300/984ea3/ffffff',
  'https://placehold.it/500x300/ff7f00/ffffff'
];

/* Start of code you have provided */
var index = 0;
var variableLen = variable.length;

function nextvariableClick() {
  index++;

  if (index == variableLen)
    index = 0;

  var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
  image.src = variable[index];

}
/* End of code you have provided */

// We execute the function to start initialise it, and set a starting image
nextvariableClick();
window.setInterval(nextvariableClick, 1000);
```

```html
<p>The function is called at runtime, and called every 1s. You should see cycling of image sources.</p>
<img id="starting_light" src="" />
```